# Why I can't get the value of this textarea?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have this line in my code to update a previous data in that textarea(there is a previous value)

```
$campo[2]='<textarea rows="3" name="desc_'.$exec->fields['recordId'].'_2" textarea_val="'.$exec->fields['description'].'" maxlength="500">';
```

But when I'm using that box in my webpage the previous value disapears... why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$campo[2]='<textarea rows="3" name="desc_'.$exec->fields['recordId'].'_2" maxlength="500">'.$exec->fields['description'].'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 5):

textarea hasn't value attribute :

```
<textarea row="3" name="textarea_name">value</textarea>
```